# clamd.amavisd Fails to start on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, clamav

I have set up a CentOS cloud server but I am having issues getting clamd amavisd to run, when I call:

> /etc/init.d/clamd.amavisd start

I get the following error:

```
Starting clamd.amavisd: /etc/init.d/functions: line 188:  2414 Killed $cgroup $nice /bin/bash -c "$corelimit >/dev/null 2>&1 ; $*"
```

I followed the installation guide as can be seen here:

http://www.howtoforge.com/perfect-server-centos-6.4-x86_64-apache2-dovecot-ispconfig-3-p4

Any help to resolve this would be massively appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you ran out of memory. This is typically what Killed means in this context. You can confirm it by checking `/var/log/messages`.

The setup you linked to will not fit into a 512MB RAM (or EC2 micro) virtual machine. You will have to cut a few things out, or use a larger virtual machine.